# Constructing a query using a php post variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database table with user info: name, email and item they committed to donate. I'd like to display what item they own on the web page, so I've constructed this query:

```
$email  = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : '';

$i = "SELECT required_items.name
      FROM required_items LEFT JOIN donations ON donations.item_id=required_items.id 
      WHERE donations.email = '" .$email. "' ";

$ir = $db->query($i);
$rows = $ir->fetchAll();

foreach($rows as $data){
$item_name = $data['name'];
}
```

Then later when I display the info:

```
<tr>
   <td><label>Item</label></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $item_name; ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

When I run the query and replace ".$email." with an email address, the query works correctly and I am able to see their donation in phpmyadmin, but as of right now with this variable in the code I only get something that just says Array.

How can I display the correct information? I eventually want it sent to the user via email so this would be very helpful.

EDIT: I've applied the advice given by STLMikey and now the $item_name displays "NULL".

Comment: are you posting information to that script? can we see your form?

Comment: Yes, I have the form before this page grab the user's email.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection attacks as it stands. You NEED to re-evaluate that SQL.(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

To actually answer your question though, your variable named `$item_name` is a collection of all the rows returned by your query. You need to loop over it to extract the desired name from each row...something like the following:

```
$rows = $ir->fetchAll();
foreach($rows as $data){
    $item_name = $data['name'];
}
```

If you can't figure out why something is printing `Array()` to the screen, try calling `print_r($var)` on your variable to view it's contents. That will print the contents of an array so you can see the internals.

Comment: I did as you said and kept my code above the same except for your changes. $item_name now returns NULL. Was there something else I should have changed that I'm not doing?

Comment: Well either, your $rows variable is null, or the $data['name'] variable is null. I'm not sure what $db manager you are using, but use the numRows method on it to verify the $ir->fetchRows() is actually returning rows so we can determine which of the two variables is our culprit